# git for-each-ref: Difference between field names `upstream` and `push`

Tags: git

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#git-for-each-ref-upstream:

> The name of a local ref which can be considered “upstream” from the displayed ref. Respects `:short`, `:lstrip` and `:rstrip` in the same way as `refname` above. Additionally respects `:track` to show "[ahead N, behind M]" and `:trackshort` to show the terse version: ">" (ahead), "<" (behind), "<>" (ahead and behind), or "=" (in sync). `:track` also prints "[gone]" whenever unknown upstream ref is encountered. Append `:track,nobracket` to show tracking information without brackets (i.e "ahead N, behind M"). Has no effect if the ref does not have tracking information associated with it. All the options apart from `nobracket` are mutually exclusive, but if used together the last option is selected.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#git-for-each-ref-push:

> The name of a local ref which represents the `@{push}` location for the displayed ref. Respects `:short`, `:lstrip`, `:rstrip`, `:track`, and `:trackshort` options as `upstream` does. Produces an empty string if no `@{push}` ref is configured.

Can anyone explain in simple terms what the difference is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to set a branch up so that it pulls from one branch but pushes to another.  For example, you could say

```
git config remote.origin.push refs/heads/*:refs/heads/dev/*
```

This doesn't change what's merged when you `pull` master (presumably `origin/master` which is the remote ref to the origin repo's `refs/heads/master`), but when you `push` your `master` changes would go to a `dev/master` branch on the origin (which, on fetch, you would see as `origin/dev/master`).

If you configure in such a way, then `upstream` is where pulls come from and `push` is where pushes go to.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a repository where the upstream for branch `br1` is set thus:

```
$ git config --get branch.br1.remote
origin
$ git config --get branch.br1.merge
refs/heads/br1
$ git config --get-all remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

In this case, the upstream for branch `br1` is `origin/br1`:

```
$ git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name "br1@{upstream}"
refs/remotes/origin/br1
```

But suppose we rename this branch to `br2`.  Its upstream remains `origin/br1`.  Suppose further that `push.default` is set to `simple`.  In this case, `git push` will refuse to push `br2` to `origin` as `br1` there, because the names do not match.

At this point, `git for-each-ref` will show you that `br2` has `origin/br1` as its upstream, but nothing as its push.

Changing the `push.default` setting (or setting up a default for the remote that overrides the global default) will change this.

As in [Mark Adelsberger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44768086/1256452), you can also set the push and fetch values to two different settings.